# ZBar SDK Get error "Multiple methods named ‘count’ found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributed"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, count, zbar-sdk

Getting error when i add ZBAR SDK

> Multiple methods named ‘count’ found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributed"

If I remove that library then its works perfectly, I have found some solution to type casting by (NSArray *) but I need to do in all file this is long process to do in whole project.

Please check below error image. I have just added library and get this error.

[image]

Please suggest

Comment: My first suggestion is that you add code examples here. Otherwise the Q will be closed. To the Q itself: Likely the receiver is id-typed so the compiler cannot decide, what version of `-count` is executed.

Comment: Hi Amin, Please check the screenshot which i added in my question.

Comment: Hi, please add code as text not as screenshot. However, this part is meaningless because it does not show the declaration of `response`. Likely it is `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Trust me your only hope is to rebuild the library after renaming the 2 count properties in ZBar to something else (say totalCount).

PS - Been there.